# How does pattern matching in Expect (TCL) work (without -re flag)?

Tags: tcl, expect

Suppose I got this string to be expected: `100:~#` or `100:~/tmp`

This really means, I need to match the terminal prompt for a machine (which may or may not contain the path). Normally, with this regex pattern:

```
100:(~|/)(/+[a-zA-Z0-9]*)*#
```

It works for an input string such as: `100:~/foo/bar/foo/baz#`

You can test it here: [Regex Pal](http://regexpal.com/)

But using Expect in TCL, I have to add `-re` to match such pattern. However, I am not allowed to do so. I tried the above pattern without regex, and it failed.

The current pattern for matching `100:~#` or `100:~/tmp` is very simple: `100:[~/]*#`, and I was told that it is shell expression for matching strings, not regular expression. The `100:[~/]*#` pattern means it matches anything between `100:[~/]` (`~` and `/` are optional) and `#`. The `*` character is meant to match anything, as opposed to the regular `*` which is zero or more in traditional regex sense.

What exactly is pattern matching expression in Expect withou `-re` flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are known as "glob" patterns. They are styled after the shell's pattern matching. The documentation is here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M40

> *****
>   Matches any sequence of characters in string, including a null string.
>
> **?**
>   Matches any single character in string.
>
> **[***chars***]**
>   Matches any character in the set given by *chars*. If a sequence of the form *x-y* appears in chars, then any character between *x* and *y*, inclusive, will match. When used with `-nocase`, the end points of the range are converted to lower case first. Whereas `{[A-z]}` matches “`_`” when matching case-sensitively (since “`_`” falls between the “`Z`” and “`a`”), with `-nocase` this is considered like {`[A-Za-z]`} (and probably what was meant in the first place).
>
> **\***x*
>   Matches the single character *x*. This provides a way of avoiding the special interpretation of the characters `*?[]\` in *pattern*.

Comment: In a glob pattern `*` is exactly like `.*` in REs, and `?` is like `.` in REs. Character sets are similar (though REs have an expanded version of them) and backslashes are much simpler in globs than REs.